# How to ensure I am programming on persistent memory

Tags: c, partitioning, persistent-memory

I am working on a final project for school that involves making a program that reads and writes to files on persistent memory. I don't have access to an actual persistent memory device so I followed the tutorial at the following link to emulate it:
https://kb.pmem.io/howto/100000012-How-To-Emulate-Persistent-Memory-using-the-Linux-memmapKernel-Option/

user@node:~/test2$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/pmem0
`Disk /dev/pmem0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes`

According to the above output, I have an emulated persistent memory partition on my dram hard drive named pmem0. I used the tutorial at the following link to get some sample code on how to read and write from files on persistent memory:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/create-a-persistent-memory-hello-world-program-using-libpmemobj-with-c.html

I compile and run the code and the output of the program says it is writing a file to persistent memory. I wanted to check if the file is being written to the correct partition so I used the command:
df -P fileName | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1 (which I got from another stackoverflow post) and the output is /dev/sda1 when I believe it should be /dev/pmem0 if it is actually using the persistent memory partition.

I'm looking for tips on how to ensure I am actually mapping my code to the persistent memory partition I created.

The code from the second link needs to have the pmdk library setup to run properly and I needed to modify my linux kernel boot parameters to setup the partition so I'm not sure if I can supply a much better minimal example.

Edit: I believe the exact lines of code I need to modify would be one of:

```
    pop = pmemobj_create(path, LAYOUT, PMEMOBJ_MIN_POOL, 0666);
    PMEMoid root = pmemobj_root(pop, sizeof (struct my_root));
    pmemobj_persist(pop, &rootp->len, sizeof (rootp->len));`
```

This creates the persistent memory pool but the tutorial doesn't seem to mention how to actually map to a persistent memory device.

Comment: What did you really use as `fileName` in _the command: `df -P fileName …`_?

Comment: @Armali The second link in the post provides a c file that writes a string to persistent memory. The usage would be ./prog -w <fileName>.  If I'm understanding the tutorial correctly, this would create a file called <fileName>, fills it with some characters, and stores it in persistent memory. I used the command to check the location of the file created from the sample program and the result just showed it was created on my regular dram hard drive.

Comment: The _hard drive_ _/dev/sda1_ isn't regularly in _**dram**_ - are you sure yours is?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. I guess a better way to phrase this is if I have a partition of persistent memory named pmem0 and write a string to persistent memory, why does the string get written to the hard drive in sda1, which I believe is regular memory?

Answer (score 0):

> why does the string get written to the hard drive in sda1, which I believe is regular memory?

The referred C program calls `pmemobj_create()` with the `path` you specify as the second program argument, in your case `fileName`. If the current working directory is on the hard drive, the created memory pool file `fileName` is of course also residing on the hard drive. If you want a file to be created on your `/dev/pmem0` disk, you have to mount that file system and use a path to a file thereon.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed the tutorial I followed did create a filsystem, mount it and name the folder /pmem0. 

I changed the file name to start with /pmem0 and it writes the file to that device. One thing I’m curious about is what happens if I write a file to that directory without using pmdk. 

For example, if I use a regular c++ program that writes to that location, do I still get the potential performance benefit of using a persistent memory device even though it isn’t written in the correct byte addressable format?

Comment: ... _the potential performance benefit of using a persistent memory device_ compared to what?